# Best way to schedule repeating jobs (AlarmManager vs Intent-filter)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have to update Data in my App every 24 hours at 2 am.
Currently, I have an Alarm via the AlarmManager which sends an alarm every 24 hours with the setRepeating method.

In the past I have experienced some unreliabilities with the timing of the alarm, so I was experimenting with an intent-filter and Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK.

My Question:
What is the difference between setting a repeated alarm every 24 hours and using an intent-filter which gets its information from the system?

Answer (score 0):

You should absolutely not do anything with ACTION_TIME_TICK.  Nor would it be reliable if you tried-  it would only work while your app is running, and if you're backgrounded you will be killed for resources.  The correct answer here is actually JobScheduler or WorkManager, depending on the nature of what you're doing.  Most likely WorkManager.  However if you were worried about the reliability of timing of an alarm, you probably are thinking about your problem wrong.  Unless you have a VERY niche use case, a bit of inaccuracy in downloading a nightly update is generally ok.  In fact it may even be welcome, to spread the load out on the server.  Your inaccuracy of dl time is likely due to Doze, which is a mechanic your use case should likely account for (Doze is a power saving mode where it reduces the frequency of timed events running when the screen is off).